# Save multiple instances of an image downloaded by wget

Tags: linux, shell

```
#!/bin/bash   
trap '.' INT
u = "URL"
if echo $u | egrep -q '^(http://|https://).+(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.JPG|\.JPEG)$'
then echo "Url checks out"
while : 
do
 wget -q $u -O picture$i.jpg
 time=$(date)
 echo "<html><head><title>Spy</title></head><body><h1>spying</h1><p>Picture 
 uploaded: $time</p><img src=\"picture$i.jpg\" width=\"300\"></body></html>"
 > spy.html
    for (( i=1; i<=10; i++))
     do
      if [$i = 10]
     then 
      rm picture$i.jpg
     else 
      mv picture$i picture$(($i+1)).jpg
      mv spy.html spy$(($i+1)).html
     fi
    done
 sleep 60
 done
 else echo "Link not accepted"
 fi
```

What it does is that the url on top is to a camera taking photos every minute. My code downloads that image, saves it and puts it in a html file every 60 seconds. 
So what I am trying to do is save the newest image in spy.html and the older ones would iteration through the loop until it reaches 10.
So newst picture in index.html then the second newest in index1.html and so on..
Running this code yields no such file on picture and the html file. This kind of makes sense, but fixing it is a different matter. 
Still looking for help on this.

Comment: You will have to make an extra file or variable that keeps track of the picture count. Then, it shold be doable. Edit: Or you can keep the script running in the background, but you would lose state at reboot and start counting from 1 again

Comment: How would it be done if keeping the script running in the background? It doesn't really matter if i have to start over after reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
#!/bin/bash   
trap '.' INT
u="URL"
counter=0 # Or 1 if you want to start counting from 1
if echo ${u} | egrep -q '^(http://|https://).+(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.JPG|\.JPEG)$'
 then echo "Url checks out"
 while : 
 do
  wget -q ${u} -O picture.jpg
  time=$(date)
  echo "<html><head><title>Spy</title></head><body><h1>spying</h1><p>Picture 
  uploaded: ${time}</p><img src=\"picture.jpg\" width=\"300\"></body></html>"
 > index_${counter}.html  # Just makes a file with the counter in it's name
  counter=counter+1 # Count's up
  sleep 60
 done
else 
 echo "Link not accepted"
fi
```

I have to say, I didn't check if it works. But I believe the rest of the code is correct, so it should.

Comment: A couple of problems with this. It does not use the original index.html file, instead it creates a index_counter0.html... index_counter1.html. I want i to start at index.html, then go up to index_9.html
The second problem is since the first picture downloaded will be the same picture in every html file.

Comment: Oh, well. Then you can only check if it is the first run of the loop and if it is then name the file index.html. As for the picture you can do the same as with the index file and add $counter, giving `picture$counter.jpg`

Comment: That's a good answer! Just one more thing, How would you check the first run? Another counter?

Comment: Just check if the counter has it's starting value like `if [counter  -eq 0] then;` Added: At the start of the loop and before `counter=counter+1` ofcourse

Comment: Thanks for the great help! Works like a charm :D Just a small tip. To be able to get a counter goin in linux, you have to do counter=$[counter + 1]

Comment: Also, if you're really fancy you could make a function for saving the picture and the HTML file so you don't have redundant code when creating the first index.html. I'll let you figure that out ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159258/discussion-between-sens-and-theskils).